# query to make duplicate entries in same table with one different value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have one table

[image]

Now I want some more entries in the table with action ="Input new" with tickettype= All the tickettypes which have action="input". I am not sure if it is doable with single statement. Please help me out if anyone knows the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is doable in one statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 
  SELECT TicketType, 'Input new' 
  FROM table1 
  WHERE Action='input'
```

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/511dd/1

Comment: can I select distinct tickettype in this statement ? Because I want to update for action like "input%" .

Comment: @PuneetPurohit yes DISTINCT can be used in this statement, like `INSERT INTO table1 SELECT DISTINCT TicketType, 'input new' ...`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
INSERT INTO [tablename]
SELECT TiketTYpe,'Input new'
From [tablename]
where Action ='input'
```